# Jupyter R crashes when plotting in docker container

Tags: r, docker, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

**I am trying to set up Jupyter using Docker. I would like to provide multiple languages kernels (python, scala, R etc.) Now it seems work for others but R. 
Everytime I execute a 'plot' function, the browser will tell me "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"**

And the error message in log is:

```
 ***caught segfault ***
 address 0x35da0, cause 'memory not mapped'
 Traceback:
 1: png(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, bg, res, antialias = antialias)
 2: dev.cb(tf)
 3: repr_recordedplot_generic(obj, ".png", TRUE, function(tf) png(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, bg, res, antialias = antialias))
 4: repr_png.recordedplot(plotobj)
 5: mime2repr[mime]
 6: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 8: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 9: tryCatch({ formats[[mime]] <- mime2repr[mime]}, error = handle_error)
 10: send_plot(last_recorded_plot)
 11: executor$execute(msg)
 12: handle_shell()
 13: kernel$run()
 14: IRkernel::main()
 aborting ... 
 [I 2016-06-08 19:41:02.360 XX restarter:103] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
 WARNING:root:kernel XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX restarted
```

If I execute a function of `png()` or `jpeg()` from the browser (Google Chrome) first, then `plot()` function could be executed successfully. I don't know why this happens, what will be changed after running `png()` or `jpeg()`. Has anyone met similar issues in either Jupyter or R?

Comment: this prbly is better served on the IRKernel github as an issue https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues (there are many of these similar issues there so you may want to consider a real environment vs a "notebook")

Comment: Yes, I have tried though.. Still haven't figured out a solution..

Answer (score 0):

This ended up avoiding using conda while downloading/installing the R packages. Instead, CRAN is used. It seems something is wrong with the compiled packages in conda.